# Nothing appears at the execution

Tags: c#

Hey people when I execute this small code the console doesn't display anything 
Im beginner in c# but my code seems correct :(

```
class Program
{
    static int Factorial(int n)
    {
        if (n==0)
        {
            return 1; //base case
        }
        else
        {
            return n * Factorial(n - 1); //recursive case
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Factorial(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not display anything because you are not calling `Console.WriteLine` anywhere

Comment: `Console.Write(Factorial(5));`

Comment: You don't write anything to the console. I can't see any `Console.WriteLine()` in your code. So what did you expect to appear on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not asking your program to write anything. The program is not supposed to write anything by itself, except if you are asking it to do so. To display an information, you need to use [Console.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) or any other function that can write information in your standard output stream.

You seem to misunderstand the purpose of the `return` statement. The goal of `return` is just to tell to the function which value it is supposed to return to the function who called it. The calling function then can store this value and treat it for additional purposes, such as printing it like you wanted to do there.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int factorialValue = Factorial(5); // factorialValue contains
                                       // the returned value of Factorial(5)

    Console.WriteLine(factorialValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't write anything to the console, If you want to display something in the console you have to write to the console for that you can use the `WriteLine()` method of the Console class. Which is an overloaded method you can check the possible overloading options [here with MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx). So the changes in your code would be like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int inputNum = 5; 
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0} is {1}",inputNum,Factorial(inputNum));
}
```

Comment: Return doesn't write on the console??
If not what does return do exactly?

Comment: @BelhassenAjmi: The return will pass some values(of type specified in the return type of the method) from the called method to the calling method, it wont do anything with console.